# Simple bar chart, populating data with for loop

Tags: python, reportlab

For example purposes I have a python application that takes in text and generates a list of the top 10 most common words, this part works fine however I would like to generate a pdf graph using reportlab, I have the following code which generates a graph:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
axis = []
d = Drawing(400, 400)

for word, frequency in top_words:
    axis.append(word)

chart = VerticalBarChart()
chart.width = 350
chart.height = 260
chart.x = 20
chart.y = 60
chart.data = data
chart.categoryAxis.categoryNames = axis
chart.valueAxis.valueMin = 0

d.add(chart)
d.save(fnRoot='Top Words', formats=['pdf'])
```

The axis is populated from within the for loop (ie the words), however for the frequency I wish to use a similar method of populating the "data" list with the frequency of words, however I seem to get all sorts of errors when doing this..

Any suggestions on how to best go about this would be great!

Comment: Please provide a minimal, working, self-contained example, so anyone willing to help can try it out.